# CSGO Comp Matches Won total not increasing

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've won at least 4 games on CSGO, my matches won have stayed at a steady 179, if I win a match it stays the same. What do I do?

Comment: You could always restart CS:GO and Steam, wait a bit for the servers to update then reopen them... This is a problem on Valve's end; there's nothing you can do unless you're an employee.

Comment: just wait... this sometimes happens.. (the matches will get updated later)

Answer (score 1):

It fixes itself after you rank up/down. I jumped 6 wins, it usually happens when you're 150-200 for some reason.